# Send sms using a number found in database table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sms

I would like to send sms using the number found inside of a database table. I tried **include function** but the message wasn't sent to a number. there is  no error shows.

```
<?php

//connect to database

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

//select database
mysqli_select_db($con, 'appointment');

if($_POST['accept'])
{
  $sql = "UPDATE service SET remarks = 'Accepted' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]"; 

 include"sms.php";
}
else if($_POST['reject'])
{
  $sql = "UPDATE service SET remarks = 'Rejected' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
}

//Execute Query
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    header("refresh:1; url=app.php");
else
    echo "Unsuccessful";
?>
```

Here's the code of my sms.php

```
<?php

$phone= "SELECT contact FROM service WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
$message= "You're Appointment is Accepted";

send_sms($phone,$message);

function send_sms($phone, $message) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $parameters = array(
    'apikey' => '*****************', //Your API KEY
    'number' => $phone,
    'message' => $message,
    'sendername' => 'SEMAPHORE' 
  );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.semaphore.co/api/v4/messages' );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

  //Send the parameters set above with the request
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $parameters ) );

  // Receive response from server
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $output = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close ($ch);

  //Show the server response
  echo "Message Successfully Delivered";
}
?>
```

I will provide a screenshot of the appointment table so that you can easily understand my problem.

[image]

Comment: PHP include/require or copy paste the code,  and then just add if else (). You don't query database, just have $phone as SQL string? $phone= "SELECT contact FROM service WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";

Comment: @LeszekRepie I tried what you've said sir. I copy paste the code but I got an error in "function send_sms($phone, $message)"..how can I solve this sir?Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I got an error in "`function send_sms($phone, $message)`"* - please include the error message verbatim *in the question*.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure `$_POST[id]` should be `$_POST["id"]`? Not sure you can reference the array like that - `id` is not a variable or a string. And what exact error message are you getting? On what line? It's much easier to diagnose a problem when we know what the symptoms are, rather than merely knowing that the problem exists.

Comment: One other thing: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: @ADyson I have an error. **Fatal error: Call to undefined function send_sms() in C:\wamp64\www\Android\Login\display.php on line 20** if i copy paste the sms code inside of an if statement.

Comment: @ADyson okay sir . I will change it after I solve this problem in sending sms.

Comment: In the question you said "If i copy paste the sms code inside of an if-else statement i've got an error ". So are you saying that this error only occurs in cases when the code is different from the code above? If so, then you need to show the version of the code which is causing the error, not a version which works.

Comment: @ADyson my sms code is working if I inserted a phone number and a message. But I want to get the phone number from the table i showed. The main reason why I ask question sir because i dont know how to implement the sms code inside of an if else and I dont know how to get number from database.\

Comment: you can google how to get the result of a mysqli query. There must be hundreds of examples of that you can find. I don't know what you mean precisely by "implement the sms code inside of an if else", it's too vague to be clear what your intention is. You can just define the function at the start of the PHP script, and then you should be able to call it from anywhere, whether that call is within an if block or not. Don't put the actual function definition within the `if` block though, that makes no sense.

Comment: @ADyson If you shows me some project like this sir and already running, I will appreciate so much sir.Thank you.

Comment: I haven't magically got an exact example of your precise scenario at my fingertips, no, especially since you still haven't really explained it properly. And anyway I'm sure you can type searches into google just as efficiently as I can. You still haven't answered my question about the if/else problem, either. I really have no idea what you mean unless you show me the code the caused the error. I cannot understand why you would ask a question about getting an error, and then paste in code which _doesn't cause the error_? How would you expect that to be helpful??

Comment: Use google: 'MySQLi' for Beginners - how to get data from DB.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending, not the phone number, but the query to your SMS service.

```
$phone= "SELECT contact FROM service WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
send_sms($phone,$message);
       ...
function send_sms($phone, $message) {
       ...
  $parameters = array(
    'apikey' => '*****************', //Your API KEY
    'number' => $phone,  /*"SELECT contact FROM service WHERE ID=$_POST[id]" */
    'message' => $message,
    'sendername' => 'SEMAPHORE' 
  );
```

Run the query and retrieve the actual phone number before trying to send it a message. (Your SMS service has no idea what to do with your query, hopefully.)

And, take seriously the SQL injection warnings in comments. Cybercriminals typically pwn vulnerable web sites like yours will be *in less than a day after they go live.* The public internet is a dangerous place. You're paying for your SMS service. You'd hate to get a bill for US$20,000 because a spammer used your service to send messages. You'd hate the loss to your reputation even more.

Comment: from the comments, OP knows this (" I want to get the phone number from the table i showed") but seemingly doesn't know how run a SQL SELECT query using mysqli and get the results, which of course is something which can be googled very easily. Then there's also some separate issue which appears to be related to a different version of the code. I take the points you make above but not sure they really actually answer the question? (IMO the question is not really answerable in its current form, though)

Comment: Understood, @ADyson. You are, of course, welcome to write your own answer.

Comment: I would, but like I said I don't think it's actually answerable as it stands, in terms of fixing the reported error message. And I'm not going to waste time repeating the 100s of examples already online of how to fetch a resultset using mysqli.